# how to get the parent page after 403 redirection using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php website and in my htaccess I have given

```
ErrorDocument 403 mydomain.com/payment-confirmation.php
```

after redirecting I want to know which is the parent URL in payment-confirmation.

Currently I got 403 page while browsing success.php ( which have alot of parameters) , so i need the value `success.php` in payment-confirmation.php 
I have checked this with `HTTP_REFERER` But not get the answer

Any solution ? Please help me

Comment: How does the user navigate through your site (e.g. what url's do they go through, what do they do on those url's)? What does the `HTTP_REFERER` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these 2 variables in your 403 handler php code:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

OR

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay. But it's not correct in my case. REQUEST_URI gives the current page name (/payment-confirmation.php) and REDIRECT_URL is blank. Any other solution , i need success.php

Comment: Make sure to define 404 ErrorDocument as: `ErrorDocument 403 /payment-confirmation.php` i.e. without domain name.